# How to get the genesis block of a running EOSIO blockchain?

Tags: nodeos, api

Given the P2P and API endpoints of a running, public EOSIO blockchain, how do I query either of them for the JSON genesis block description of that running blockchain?

Specifically, I want to discover the contents of a "genesis.json" file that I can pass to nodeos like this:

`nodeos --genesis-json=genesis.json`

Alternatively, is there any way I can connect and synchronize with a running blockchain with API and P2P endpoits without needing out-of-band information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, fetching genesis.json from other running nodes is not supported. The genesis block is a starting point of verifying all following blocks, and it needs a manual verification by its design. It's not difficult to make an remote API to extract genesis.json from existing blocks.log, but I don't think it would be added to nodeos soon.

In snapshot, you can have all information to make it available to start block synchronization.